# pyodbc: Unable to connect to a local database. How to read the error `('H000', '[H000] [unixODBC][ (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')``?

Tags: pyodbc, unixodbc

I'm having some trouble using pyodbc against a local mysql database. Here's some version information:

```
➜  ~ python3 --version
Python 3.6.2

➜  ~ pip3 show pyodbc
Name: pyodbc
Version: 4.0.21
Summary: DB API Module for ODBC
Home-page: https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc
Author: Michael Kleehammer
Author-email: michael@kleehammer.com
License: MIT
Location: /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages
Requires:

➜  ~ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.4
DRIVERS............: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /Users/cognite/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8

➜  ~ cat /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbcinst.ini
[ODBC Drivers]
MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver = Installed
MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver    = Installed
MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver         = Installed

[ODBC Connection Pooling]
PerfMon    = 0
Retry Wait =

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver]
Driver = /usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-macos10.12-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc5w.so

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver]
Driver = /usr/local/mysql-connector-odbc-5.3.9-macos10.12-x86-64bit/lib/libmyodbc5a.so

[MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver]
Driver = /usr/local/lib/libmyodbc5w.so

➜  ~ cat /usr/local/Cellar/unixodbc/2.3.4/etc/odbc.ini
[ODBC Data Sources]
myodbc  = MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
myodbca = MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver

[ODBC]
Trace         = 0
TraceAutoStop = 0
TraceFile     =
TraceLibrary  =

[myodbc]
Driver = MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver
SERVER = localhost
PORT   = 3306

[myodbca]
Driver = MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver
SERVER = localhost
PORT   = 3306
```

I can clearly see the `test` database when I login to mysql (using `mysql -u root -p` and then entering the password). `show databases` gives:

```
...
| mysql                                                |
| performance_schema                                   |
| sys                                                  |
| test                                                 |
+------------------------------------------------------+
189 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

So I'm not sure why my connection attempt with pyodbc are failing. Here's the python code I'm trying to connect with and the output I'm seeing:

```
import pyodbc


pyodbc.drivers()
# ['ODBC Drivers', 'ODBC Connection Pooling', 'MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver', 'MySQL ODBC 5.3 ANSI Driver', 'MySQL ODBC 5.3 Driver']

CONNECTION_STRING = "driver={MySQL ODBC 5.3 Unicode Driver};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=test;UID=root;PWD=root;CHARSET=UTF8" 

conn = pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
# pyodbc.Error: ('H000', '[H000] [unixODBC][ (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

What does the error mean? Any help with figuring how I can make the connection to my local database would be appreciated.

Update: I had to use the Ansi driver, and then it worked. But my question still stands: What does that error message mean? How can I get more information about the error? I would have liked it to say something along the lines of "unable to connect to the database with this driver".

Comment: *"How can I get more information about the error?"* - Perhaps try tweaking the `Trace` and `TraceFile` settings and then see if the ODBC trace file shows anything more specific.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing exactly the same on OSX. However, on Ubuntu it works fine, even using the Unicode driver.

Comment: I'm sorry, no. I didn't investigate it further because I only needed it to work in ubuntu-based docker images.

Comment: Thank you for the update. 
I was able to connect as well by changing to ANSI driver.
However, the query result outputs ANSI language; something like 'R\x00e\x00s\x00e\x00a...'
Did you experience the same?
Any suggestion for a workaround?